# Is the following binary relation a strict linear order?

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Textbook answer: No.

The binary relation:

(X, P), where X = $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and $(a,b)P(s,t)$ iff $a > s$ and $b > t$

Linear order: Relation P that is asymmetric, transitive, and complete.

Complete: For all $(a,b),(s,t) \in$ X, $(a,b)P(s,t)$ or $(s,t)P(a,b)$ or both and $(a,b) \neq (s,t)$

The reason this binary relation is not a strict linear order is because it is not complete, right?

However, I cannot seem to understand why it is not a strict linear order. It is definitely irreflexive and transitive, right? For completeness, isn't the Cartesian plane naturally ordered? Or am I missing something?

Comment: $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ are incomparable in this ordering, for example

Comment: I think I get it now! It is not complete because ((2,3),(3,2)) and ((3,2),(2,3)) are not in the relation.

Comment: Incidentally, the [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on $\Bbb R^2$ _is_ a total ordering